# jQTouch - unable to find proper documentation/reference

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, jqtouch

I'm learning jQTouch from scratch. What is the best way to learn it?

I don't seem to be able to find any proper documentation, does that mean the best way is to dig into the css itself? And keep trying?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what "proper documentation" means to you. They have certainly got some documentation, although I agree that it can be made much more comprehensive.

You should start with their [Getting Started](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/gettingstarted) article. Then have a look at the available [initialisation options](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/initoptions), [callback events](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/callbackevents), [animations](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/animations), etc. These are all listed on their [wiki homepage](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/).

The best resource is probably the [demo](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/), that you would be able to see most of the actions with a WebKit browser.

Peepcode has a nice [introductory video tutorial on jQTouch](https://peepcode.com/products/jqtouch) that costs a little bit. If you're evaluating it, you may want to give it a go.